# Adding a new key to the dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list called `rest` which contains many dictionaries in a list which is in the format

```
rest = [{'a':'b','c':'d','e':'f'}, {'a':'g','c':'h','e':'i}, {'a':'j','c':'k','e':'l'}]
```

Can I get an output as below where I have new as a key inside a dictionary for all the key-value pair except the first key-value pair

```
output =[{'a':'b','new':{'c':'d','e':'f'}},{'a':'g','new':{'c':'h','e':'i}},{'a':'j','new':{'c':'k','e':'l'}}]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No. Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. Also, what you have written is not valid Python. Did you mean to have everything as a string?

Comment: It's not possible.  A given key can only occur once (at most) in a dictionary.  Any attempt to assign a second value to the same key will just overwrite the first one.  If this is some sort of a class assignment, is it possible that you didn't understand what you're supposed to do?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Do you mind explaining why you’re trying to assign different values to the same key?

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you please check now ?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by other comments you cannot have multiple same keys in a dictionary. You should reconsider your example. You can have a list for the same key in a dictionary like this:

```
from pprint import pprint


rest = [{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}, {"a":"g","c":"h","e":"i"}, {"a":"j","c":"k","e":"l"}]
output = {
    "hello": []
    }

for item in rest:
    output["hello"].append(item)

pprint(output)
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you please check now ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the keys and values in the `res` are just for demonstration purpose. If not, then as mentioned in other comments, you should enclose them within quotes.

Masoud's answer could solve your problem. Otherwise, you can have list of dictionaries as shown below:
    `output = [{"hello": {a:b,c:d,e:f}}, {"hello": {a:g,c:h,e:i}}, {"hello": {a:j,c:k,e:l}}]`

Answer (score 0):

Key values in a python dictionary have to be unique.
Also strings should be places inside a single `''` or double`""` quotes.

One valid way is

`output = {'hello':{'a':'b','c':'d','e':'f'},
          'hello1':{'a':'g','c':'h','e':'i'},
          'hello2':{'a':'j','c':'k','e':'l'} }`

Comment: I have edited the question. Can u please check now ?